# Swift AVFoundation can't publish updates while view updates

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I have some code below that records videos using AVFoundation. When my app launches I get the warning "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior" on the line "@StateObject var cameraModel = CameraViewModel()". I tried debugging this but couldn't find a way to get ride of it. Is this related to using @StateObject?

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct HomeStory: View {
  @StateObject var cameraModel = CameraViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
      ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      }
  }
}

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
  @EnvironmentObject var cameraModel : CameraViewModel
  var size: CGSize
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UIView {
      let view = UIView()
      
      cameraModel.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: cameraModel.session)
      cameraModel.preview.frame.size = size
      
      cameraModel.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
      view.layer.addSublayer(cameraModel.preview)
      
      DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
          cameraModel.session.startRunning()
      }
      
      return view
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) { }
}


class CameraViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
  @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
  @Published var alert = false
  @Published var output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
  @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
  @Published var isRecording: Bool = false
  @Published var recordedURLs: [URL] = []
  @Published var previewURL: URL?
  @Published var showPreview: Bool = false
  @Published var recordedDuration: CGFloat = 0
  @Published var maxDuration: CGFloat = 20
  
  func checkPermission(){
      
      switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
      case .authorized:
          setUp()
          return
      case .notDetermined:
          AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
              
              if status{
                  self.setUp()
              }
          }
      case .denied:
          self.alert.toggle()
          return
      default:
          return
      }
  }
  
  func setUp(){
      
      do{
          self.session.beginConfiguration()
          let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
          let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice!)
          let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
          let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
          
          // MARK: Audio Input
          
          if self.session.canAddInput(videoInput) && self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){
              self.session.addInput(videoInput)
              self.session.addInput(audioInput)
          }

          if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
              self.session.addOutput(self.output)
          }
          
          self.session.commitConfiguration()
      }
      catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
  }
  
  func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

  }
  
  func mergeVideos(assets: [AVURLAsset],completion: @escaping (_ exporter: AVAssetExportSession)->()) async {

  }
}
```

Comment: It is related to the fact that you are setting Published properties inside makeUIView. You should not do that.

Comment: Note, it looks like you are using a background thread in `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {...}`, try using the main thread.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I have to use a background thread for that operation. Using the main thread or simply calling **startRunning** results in a swift ui error that prompts me to call it in a background thread.

Comment: @jnpdx what should I do to avoid this? Can I call everything from the UpdateUIView? Would you demonstrate how please, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: so, you tried this `DispatchQueue.main.async {  //...  cameraModel code  ...   codecameraModel.session.startRunning() }` and it did not work, is that correct?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine when I use the code in your comment instead of what I have I get the purple error "-[AVCaptureSession startRunning] should be called from background thread. Calling it on the main thread can lead to UI unresponsiveness" and the app freezes.

Comment: Looks to me like all of the cameraModel.preview lines should be in the init of the view model. Also, I don’t think (from the code you’ve shown) that there’s any reason for preview to be Published.

Comment: @jnpdx I tried to move the code in the makeuiview to the init of the viewModel but couldn't figure out the proper way to do this. How do you suggest I accomplish this? You said the view doesn't have to be published, does this simply mean to remove the Published label from the session in the viewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the main issue is the modification of [`@Published` properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) of your `CameraViewModel` inside the `makeUIView` method of `CameraPreview`... which is generally discouraged in SwiftUI, as it can lead to unexpected behavior or warnings.

You might consider moving the camera setup code from [`makeUIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/makeuiview(context:)) to the initializer of `CameraViewModel`. That will make sure the camera is configured when the view model is created, rather than when the view is rendered.

Since starting the camera session can be time-consuming and can block the main thread, it is correct to perform this operation in the background. However, any UI updates or state changes that result from this operation should be dispatched back to the main thread.

If the `preview` property of your view model does not need to be observed by any SwiftUI views for changes, it does not need to be marked with `@Published`. That will prevent SwiftUI from trying to re-render views when this property changes.

`CameraViewModel` would then be:

```swift
class CameraViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    // Other @Published properties

    var preview: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.setupCamera()
    }

    private func setupCamera() {
        // Setup your camera here, similar to your existing setUp() method.
        // Do not forget to check and request permission if necessary.
    }

    // Rest of your code
}
```

And `CameraPreview` `UIViewRepresentable`:

```swift
struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var cameraModel : CameraViewModel
    var size: CGSize
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        guard let preview = cameraModel.preview else { return view }

        preview.frame = view.bounds
        preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(preview)

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            if !self.cameraModel.session.isRunning {
                self.cameraModel.session.startRunning()
            }
        }
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) { }
}
```

The `preview` layer is prepared during the view model's initialization and only added to the view in `makeUIView`.
The session start is kept on a background thread to avoid freezing the UI, but make sure any UI updates or state changes triggered by background operations are dispatched to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, last question for video, Id appreciate the help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77598109/avfoundation-swift-toggling-front-and-back-camera-causes-bug