# AVFoundation Swift Toggling Front and Back Camera causes bug

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, video, avfoundation

I have a video recorder built with AVFoundation in Swift. The Recorder can take multiple clips and connect them into one video. For example you can start the video then stop it, then start it again and stop it; the final video will be both clips combined. If I take the first video using the front camera then stop the clip, toggle to the back camera and take another clip then a final clip is made successfully. However if I take one clip using both the front and back camera then the video fails and the clip doesn't process. Why does toggling between the camera perspective during a video cause this problem?

UPDATE

```
   func switchCamera() {
       if isRecording {
           stopRecording(shouldToggle: false)
       }

       flipCamera()

       if isRecording {
           startRecording()
       }
   }
   func stopRecording(shouldToggle: Bool){
       output.stopRecording()
       if shouldToggle {
           isRecording = false
       }
   }
```

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
   @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
   @Published var alert = false
   @Published var output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
   @Published var preview: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
   @Published var isRecording: Bool = false
   @Published var recordedURLs: [URL] = []
   @Published var previewURL: URL?
   @Published var showPreview: Bool = false
   @Published var recordedDuration: CGFloat = 0
   @Published var maxDuration: CGFloat = 20
   var currentCameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .back
   
   override init() {
       super.init()
       self.checkPermission()
       self.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
       self.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
   }

   func flipCamera() {
       // Create a discovery session to find all available video devices
       let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)

       // Get all available video devices
       let videoDevices = discoverySession.devices

       // Check if there is more than one video device
       guard videoDevices.count > 1 else {
           return // If not, return early
       }

       // Get the current input
       guard let currentVideoInput = session.inputs.first as? AVCaptureDeviceInput else {
           return
       }

       // Get the new camera position
       let newCameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back

       // Find the new camera device
       if let newCamera = videoDevices.first(where: { $0.position == newCameraPosition }) {
           // Create a new video input
           do {
               let newVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera)

               // Remove the current input
               session.removeInput(currentVideoInput)

               // Add the new input
               if session.canAddInput(newVideoInput) {
                   session.addInput(newVideoInput)
                   currentCameraPosition = newCameraPosition
               } else {
                   // Handle the case where adding the new input fails
                   print("Failed to add new camera input")
               }
           } catch {
               // Handle any errors that occur while creating the new input
               print("Error creating new camera input: \(error.localizedDescription)")
           }
       }
   }
   
   func checkPermission(){
       switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
       case .authorized:
           checkAudioPermission()
           return
       case .notDetermined:
           AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
               if status {
                   self.checkAudioPermission()
               }
           }
       case .denied:
           self.alert.toggle()
           return
       default:
           return
       }
   }
   
   func checkAudioPermission() {
       switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) {
       case .authorized:
           setUp()
           return
       case .notDetermined:
           AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { (audioStatus) in
               if audioStatus {
                   self.setUp()
               }
           }
       case .denied:
           self.alert.toggle()
           return
       default:
           return
       }
   }
   
   func setUp(){
       do {
           self.session.beginConfiguration()
           let cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
           let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice!)
           let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
           let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)

           if self.session.canAddInput(videoInput) && self.session.canAddInput(audioInput){
               self.session.addInput(videoInput)
               self.session.addInput(audioInput)
           }

           if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
               self.session.addOutput(self.output)
           }
           self.session.commitConfiguration()
       }
       catch{
           print(error.localizedDescription)
       }
   }
   
   func startRecording(){
       // MARK: Temporary URL for recording Video
       let tempURL = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "\(Date()).mov"
       output.startRecording(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempURL), recordingDelegate: self)
       isRecording = true
   }
   
   func stopRecording(){
       output.stopRecording()
       isRecording = false
   }
   
   func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
       if let error = error {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
           return
       }
       
       // CREATED SUCCESSFULLY
       print(outputFileURL)
       self.recordedURLs.append(outputFileURL)
       if self.recordedURLs.count == 1{
           self.previewURL = outputFileURL
           return
       }
       
       // CONVERTING URLs TO ASSETS
       let assets = recordedURLs.compactMap { url -> AVURLAsset in
           return AVURLAsset(url: url)
       }
       
       self.previewURL = nil
       // MERGING VIDEOS
       Task {
           await mergeVideos(assets: assets) { exporter in
               exporter.exportAsynchronously {
                   if exporter.status == .failed{
                       // HANDLE ERROR
                       print(exporter.error!)
                   }
                   else{
                       if let finalURL = exporter.outputURL{
                           print(finalURL)
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               self.previewURL = finalURL
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   
   func mergeVideos(assets: [AVURLAsset],completion: @escaping (_ exporter: AVAssetExportSession)->()) async {
       
       let compostion = AVMutableComposition()
       var lastTime: CMTime = .zero
       
       guard let videoTrack = compostion.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else{return}
       guard let audioTrack = compostion.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else{return}
       
       for asset in assets {
           // Linking Audio and Video
           do {
               try await videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.load(.duration)), of: asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .video)[0], at: lastTime)
               // Safe Check if Video has Audio
               if try await !asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .audio).isEmpty {
                   try await audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.load(.duration)), of: asset.loadTracks(withMediaType: .audio)[0], at: lastTime)
               }
           }
           catch {
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
           
           // Updating Last Time
           do {
               lastTime = try await CMTimeAdd(lastTime, asset.load(.duration))
           } catch {
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
       
       // MARK: Temp Output URL
       let tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "Reel-\(Date()).mp4")
       
       // VIDEO IS ROTATED
       // BRINGING BACK TO ORIGNINAL TRANSFORM
       
       let layerInstructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
       
       // MARK: Transform
       var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
       transform = transform.rotated(by: 90 * (.pi / 180))
       transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -videoTrack.naturalSize.height)
       layerInstructions.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)
       
       let instructions = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
       instructions.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: lastTime)
       instructions.layerInstructions = [layerInstructions]
       
       let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
       videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: videoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: videoTrack.naturalSize.width)
       videoComposition.instructions = [instructions]
       videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
       
       guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: compostion, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else{return}
       exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
       exporter.outputURL = tempURL
       exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
       completion(exporter)
   }
}


//IGNORE NOT IMPORTANT TO QUESTION
struct HomeStory: View {
   @StateObject var cameraModel = CameraViewModel()
   
   var body: some View {
       ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
           CameraStoryView()
               .environmentObject(cameraModel)
               .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
               .padding(.top,10)
               .padding(.bottom,30)
           
           ZStack {
               Button {
                   if cameraModel.isRecording {
                       cameraModel.stopRecording()
                   } else {
                       cameraModel.startRecording()
                   }
               } label: {
                   if cameraModel.isRecording {
                       Circle().frame(width: 95, height: 95).foregroundStyle(.red).opacity(0.7)
                   } else {
                       ZStack {
                           Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                           Circle().stroke(.white, lineWidth: 7).frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                       }.frame(width: 95, height: 95)
                   }
               }
               
               Button {
                   cameraModel.flipCamera()
               } label: {
                   Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.camera")
                       .font(.title)
                       .foregroundColor(.white)
                       .padding()
                       .background(Circle().fill(Color.black.opacity(0.7)))
               }.offset(x: -100)
               
               Button {
                   if let _ = cameraModel.previewURL {
                       cameraModel.showPreview.toggle()
                   }
               } label: {
                   if cameraModel.previewURL == nil && !cameraModel.recordedURLs.isEmpty {
                       ProgressView().tint(.black)
                   } else {
                       HStack {
                           Text("Preview")
                           Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                       }
                       .padding()
                       .foregroundColor(.black).font(.body)
                       .background {
                           Capsule().foregroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
                       }
                   }
               }
               .padding(.horizontal,20)
               .padding(.vertical,8)
               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .trailing)
               .padding(.trailing)
               .opacity((cameraModel.previewURL == nil && cameraModel.recordedURLs.isEmpty) || cameraModel.isRecording ? 0 : 1)
           }
           .frame(maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .bottom)
           .padding(.bottom,10)
           .padding(.bottom,30)
           
           Button {
               cameraModel.recordedDuration = 0
               cameraModel.previewURL = nil
               cameraModel.recordedURLs.removeAll()
           } label: {
               Image(systemName: "xmark")
                   .font(.title)
                   .foregroundColor(.white)
           }
           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .topLeading)
           .padding()
           .padding(.top)
           .opacity(!cameraModel.recordedURLs.isEmpty && cameraModel.previewURL != nil && !cameraModel.isRecording ? 1 : 0)
       }
       .overlay(content: {
           if let url = cameraModel.previewURL, cameraModel.showPreview {
               FinalPreview(url: url, showPreview: $cameraModel.showPreview)
                   .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
           }
       })
       .animation(.easeInOut, value: cameraModel.showPreview)
       .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
   }
}
struct FinalPreview: View {
   var url: URL
   @Binding var showPreview: Bool
   
   var body: some View {
       GeometryReader { proxy in
           let size = proxy.size
           
           VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
               .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
               .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
               .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
               .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                   Button {
                       showPreview.toggle()
                   } label: {
                       Label {
                           Text("Back")
                       } icon: {
                           Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                       }
                       .foregroundColor(.white)
                   }
                   .padding(.leading)
                   .padding(.top,22)
               }
       }
   }
}

struct CameraStoryView: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var cameraModel: CameraViewModel
   var body: some View {
       
       GeometryReader { proxy in
           let size = proxy.size
           
           CameraPreview(size: size).environmentObject(cameraModel)
          
       }
       .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 0.01, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { _ in
           if cameraModel.recordedDuration <= cameraModel.maxDuration && cameraModel.isRecording{
               cameraModel.recordedDuration += 0.01
           }
           
           if cameraModel.recordedDuration >= cameraModel.maxDuration && cameraModel.isRecording{
               cameraModel.stopRecording()
               cameraModel.isRecording = false
           }
       }
   }
}

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
   @EnvironmentObject var cameraModel : CameraViewModel
   var size: CGSize
   
   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
       let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
       guard let preview = cameraModel.preview else { return view }

       preview.frame = view.bounds
       preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
       view.layer.addSublayer(preview)

       DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
           if !self.cameraModel.session.isRunning {
               self.cameraModel.session.startRunning()
           }
       }
       
       return view
   }
   
   func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this using the standard camera app? I don’t think it’s supported there.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yea it's not supported on the standard camera, but apps like SnapChat have done it. I think if its not possibly to continuously play the video while flipping the camera then its definitely possible to make a new clip every time the camera flips and join them into one at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have you tried this using the standard camera app? I do not think it is supported there.

The functionality of toggling between the front and back cameras during an ongoing video recording session is not typically supported in the standard camera app on most smartphones, including iPhones.
In the standard camera app, users generally need to select the desired camera (front or back) before starting the video recording.

In your `flipCamera()` function, you are correctly switching the camera input, but there might be additional steps needed to handle the transition between inputs seamlessly during an ongoing recording session.

If you would like to explore if this is even feasible, you should make sure the session configuration is updated atomically, reducing the chances of inconsistencies during the camera switch.

> I can't add a completion handler to the `fileOutput` function.
> But instead, I can move `flipCamera` and `startRecording` to the beginning of the `fileOutput` function. So they only get called after the season `finishes` recording the first clip.
> This works perfectly and makes it seem like a continuous video.

The principle here is to make sure the camera flip and the start of the new recording session occur only after the previous recording session has been completely finalized. That approach helps in maintaining session integrity and avoiding conflicts between session configurations.

The `stopRecording` function is called to end the current recording session. However, this function does not immediately flip the camera or start a new recording.

In the `fileOutput(_:didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:)` delegate method, which is called when a recording session finishes, the OP added the logic to flip the camera and start a new recording. That makes sure these actions are only executed after the previous recording is completely stopped and finalized.

The `flipCamera` and `startRecording` functions are called at the beginning of the `fileOutput(_:didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:)` method. That sequential arrangement makes sure as soon as one recording session ends, the system prepares for the next session by flipping the camera and initiating a new recording.

```swift
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    // First, handle any errors
    if let error = error {
        print("Recording finished with error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    // Append the recorded URL
    self.recordedURLs.append(outputFileURL)

    // Now flip the camera and start a new recording if needed
    if shouldContinueRecording {
        flipCamera()
        startRecording()
    }
}

func flipCamera() {
    // implementation of flipping the camera 
}

func startRecording() {
    // implementation of starting a new recording 
}

func stopRecording(shouldToggle: Bool) {
    output.stopRecording() // That is asynchronous
    isRecording = false
}
```

So, `flipCamera` and `startRecording` are only called after the current recording is completely stopped, as indicated by the `fileOutput(_:didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:)` method being triggered.
That would provide a more reliable and stable way to handle the transition between recording sessions, especially when changing camera inputs.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work though. I added an update in my question with some new functions. When the user switches the camera the switchcamera function is called. Basically it's supposed to end the current video, then make a new video for the new camera perspective. The the goal is for these clips to be merged together. However when I try this only the final clip is saved and shown. So if I take a video and flip the camera three times, then the last camera position clip is saved. Why are they all not being saved in the **recordedURLs** array then merged.

Comment: @ahmed I have edited the answer to leave some suggestions/checks for you to consider.

Comment: Thanks, the fileoutput function Is correctly called when the switch camera function is called, but it returns in the beginning due to the error "Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11818 "Recording Stopped" UserInfo={AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=true, NSLocalizedDescription=Recording Stopped, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop any other actions using the recording device and try again., AVErrorRecordingFailureDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x2825e94a0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16414 "(null)"}}"

Comment: Commenting out the **flipCamera()** function inside **switchCamera()** gets ride of this error and the clip is saved to the **recordedURLs** array correctly. It seems like calling the flip camera function after stopping the recording makes the file output function fail. Is this due to **session.removeInput(currentVideoInput)** inside the code for your flipCamera() function? Or is there something else causing this issue?

Comment: @ahmed OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I can't add a completion handler to the **fileOutput** function. But instead I can move flipCamera and startRecording to the beginning of the fileOutput function. So they only get called after the season finishes recording the first clip. This works perfectly and makes it seem like a continuous video. Thanks!

Comment: @ahmed Great, well done. I have cleaned up the answer to include only your conclusion. Please let me know if I missed anything.